# clojure.lang.Repl deprecated in IntelliJ with Cursive

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

When I run the Cursive repl in IntelliJ, the following warning is displayed:

```
WARNING: clojure.lang.Repl is deprecated.
Instead, use clojure.main like this:
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i init.clj -r args...
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue within IntelliJ?

To get to this point I:

1. Followed the [Cursive instructions](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/repl.html) for setup.
2. Double-checked that `lein repl` works from my terminal.
3. Double-checked that the Cursive repl is running on the correct namespace.
4. Researched and found many workarounds relating to [a similar issue](https://github.com/mreid/clojure-framework) in the actual Clojure Framework.

For the time being, in order to execute `(-main)` from the repl I am first running `(in-ns 'fileName)` to enter the correct namespace and then executing the -main function. I have found this preferable to typing out the full `(fileName/-main)` every time, but this is still not an ideal workaround.

Comment: You may also wish to join the Cursive mailing list for faster response:  https://cursive-ide.com/mailinglist.html

Comment: What is your OS?  Java version?  leiningen version?